# Шрифт для проектов по умолчанию VisualStudio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, шрифты

В `Visual Studio` для объектов по умолчанию используется шрифт `SegoeUI`, и соответвенно, при использовании другого шрифта, например, `HelveticaNeueCyr`, приходится постоянно вручную везде менять шрифты. Есть ли какая ни будь возможность установить свой шрифт по умолчанию для создаваемых проектов/объектов?

Comment: Нужно копать в сторону файлов шаблонов кода, лежащих где-то в файлах VS. Помню что для C/C++ шаблоны можно было кастомизировать, вероятно, это возможно и для WinForms.

Comment: @nzeemin Мне хотя бы для `Wpf` уже сойдет решение

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что вам нужно вот это:

**Настройка шаблонов проектов и элементов**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms247119.aspx

**Практическое руководство. Обновление существующих шаблонов**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms185319.aspx